# What's the best way to make a continuous loop to get information from iTunes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, loops, nstimer

I'd like to make a continuous loop to get information from iTunes to get stuff like: the player position (1:37), current track being played, etc... I'm using `iTunes.h` and `ScriptingBridge` to get the iTunes Data.
I have tried using `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(getInformation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` but from what I've seen on the Activity Monitor this consumes a lot of the CPU and if, for example, I press a button inside the `NSWindow` where I have the `NSTimer`, the UI of my App, that supposedly was going to be updated, is not updated. If I let go of the button the UI starts updating normally.

I have also tried using a `while(1){}` but for some reason my App freezes.

Does any1 have any idea on how to perform what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that'll burn CPU like crazy.. dont poll!

---

sign up for the distributed notification:

```
//the distributed notification sent
#define SONG_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION @"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo"
```

---

shameless advertisment: look at source of DDBoomBox on github which does EXACTLY what you wanna do :)

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/BoomBox

Comment: thanks for your answer! and your code from github seems really helpful ;) got what I needed!